# i don't know what's wrong with it can you analyze if possible

Tags: system, oledb

I have based my codes from my professors. I typed the right username and password but it keeps on saying invalid user. The name of the table is also correct. I don't know why it keeps on saying it's an invalid user kindly help me please.

```
If Len(Trim(txtUsername.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter user name", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtUsername.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(txtPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter password", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtPassword.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Users"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ExecuteQuery(query)

    Dim ctr As Integer
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If (dt.Rows(ctr)("Username")) = txtUsername.Text Then
            If (dt.Rows(ctr)("Password")) = txtPassword.Text Then
                frmMainMenu.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect password")
            txtPassword.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Focus()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid user")
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtUsername.Text = ""
        txtUsername.Focus()

    End If
```

Comment: Well you select the whole table which will return all the users in a list and then you compare the user name and password to one of them not all of them. You SQL should be paramterized and you should execute something like `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?`

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing the dt DataTable.  So a new DataTable will have 0 rows, and you will fall into the Else of `If dt.Rows.Count > 0`.  I presume you had intended to have dt be the DataTable that results from the ExecuteQuery statement, but as you are neither passing dt in nor assigning a result from ExecuteQuery to the dt variable, it is still blank.

Not knowing what ExecuteQuery does, I would imagine it should be either

```
ExecuteQuery(query, dt)
```

or

```
dt = ExecuteQuery(query)
```

After which point you might fall into the intended username/password comparison block, if there are actually rows in the Users table.

However your matching still will not work unless the matching record is the first in the DataTable, as you never actually iterate/increment ctr.

Answer (score 0):

this is my codes for ExecuteQuery()

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nikko\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PayrollSystemThesis\PayrollSystemThesis\bin\Debug\Thesis.accdb"
Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim dbCon As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dbDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, dbCon)
        Dim dbCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dbDA)
        Dim dbDT As New DataTable
        dbDA.Fill(dbDT)
        Return dbDT
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

it reads sql statements.